# Move all files and folder from html/folder to html/ using linux command

Tags: linux, command, putty

I tried this command  mv -v html/folder html/

but, it gives error that they are same folder

Comment: can you show your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/how-to-move-all-files-and-folders-via-mv-command, this should work:

```
mv html/folder/* html/
```